# Why is Windows 10 not fetching all available WiFi connections in my PC? One is missing

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, ssid

I have a computer running Windows 10. My problem is that, one WiFi connection "RAJ" is not showing all other are available and connecting.

I pressed forgot on the "RAJ"
connection once. Now, how do I connect to "RAJ" again, even manual WLAN connection is also not connection in task bar.

Comment: If this is your router, change the name of the SSID.

Comment: Was the network you cannot see previously hidden?  https://www.maketecheasier.com/block-wifi-network-windows10/

Comment: What if you create a hotspot by the same name on your mobile phone? Does Windows 10 now see it?

Comment: Have you tried turning wifi off and on again?

Answer (score 3):

You might not see the name `RAJ` in the WiFi connection list, but treat the WiFi connection [as if it were hidden](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-connect-hidden-wireless-networks-windows-10/), and connect accordingly.

- Open the WiFi connection list.
- Scroll down to *Hidden Network* and select it.

[image: Hidden Network select]

- Enter the network name, and then the password.

If that does not work, here are two more alternatives.

- Change the name of the hidden WiFi network on the router, and try connecting as above using the new name.
- Remove any bad WiFi logins with [Regedit](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/delete-wifi-network-profile-windows), and try connecting as above using the new name. **N.B.** Editing the Windows Reagistry involves risks.

[image: Hidden network entry]

Comment: sir, in my system no hidden networks, added manually but found no use.